# Snake-like continuum vs Peano continuum

Tags: metric-spaces, continuum-theory

A snake-like continuum is a continuum such that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exist a collection of open sets $d_1,d_2,\ldots d_n$ with diameters les than $\varepsilon$ such that $d_i \cap d_j\neq \emptyset$ iff $|i-j|\leq 1$ and $X=\cup_{i=1}^n d_i$.

A Peano continuum is a continuum such that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exist a collection of connected sets $d_1,d_2,\ldots d_n$ with diameters les than $\varepsilon$ such that  $X=\cup_{i=1}^n d_i$.

Triod is an example of a Peano continua that is not snake-like.

My question is: Are all snake-like continua a Peano continua too? If the answer is affirmative, it is enough to prove that any open set can be represented as a finite union of connected sets (is that true for metric spaces?). Otherwise we should find a counterexample.

Comment: $\neq \emptyset$. I'll edit it now. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure! :)

Comment: Are you sure you want a continuum rather than a path connected compact metric space?

Comment: @MoisheKohan The definitions stated in the questions are for continua. I don't get your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you insist of having a continuum, here is a counter-example:

Let $X$ be the subset of $R^2$ which is the union of the graph of the function
$$
y=\sin(1/x), 0<x\le 1
$$
and the vertical interval $\{(0,y): -1\le y\le 1\}$.

[image]

I leave it to you to check that $X$ is a snake-like continuum. It is not a Peano continuum since it is not even path-connected.

However, I do not have examples of path-connected snake-like  continua which are not Peano. There is a good chance, they do not exist.